# How to access "groups" using "class-transformer" in nested components

Tags: javascript, typescript, metadata, decorator, class-transformer

I'm trying to limit access to some properties to only users with that property on their group in a deeply nested interface, and I'm unable to access the "groups" metadata in the nested components.

Here is a code example:

Example of response:

```
export class ProductResponseInterface {
  // groups work fine here 
  @ValidateNested()
  success: boolean;

  @Type(() => ProductFetchResponseInterface)
  data?: ProductFetchResponseInterface;

  error?: string;

  @Exclude()
  groups?: string[];

  constructor(partial: Partial<ProductResponseInterface>) {
    Object.assign(this, partial);
  }
}


export class ProductFetchResponseInterface {
  // groups seem to be undefined here 
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => ProductInterface)
  @Expose({ groups: ['eshop.products'] })
  products: ProductInterface[];
  @Exclude()
  groups: string[];
  count: number;

  constructor(partial: Partial<ProductFetchResponseInterface>) {
    Object.assign(this, partial);
  }
}

export class ProductInterface {
  // groups seems to be undefined here 
  @Expose({ groups: ['eshop.products.product.id', 'admin'] })
  id: number;
  @Expose({ groups: ['eshop.products.product.name'] })
  name: string;
  ...

  constructor(partial: Partial<ProductInterface>) {
    Object.assign(this, partial);
  }
}
```

**The problem:**
ProductFetchResponseInterface and ProductInterface don't have access to the "groups" tag, and their response returns empty products.

This is the call that uses those interfaces

```
    const http_response = await this.handle_request(url);
    // { success: true, data: { products: [ { id: 1, name: 'product_name' }]}}
    return plainToInstance(
      ProductResponseInterface,
      {
        ...response,
        groups: user.access_permissions_populated // ['eshop.products', 'eshop.products.product.id',...],
      },
      {},
    );
```

Any idea on how to make it work?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need call plainToInsatnce like this

```
plainToInstance(ProductResponseInterface, plainObject, { groups: ["eshop.products", "eshop.products.product.name", "eshop.products.product.id"] })
```

There is test example

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { plainToInstance } from "class-transformer"
import { ProductResponseInterface } from "./test"

describe("", () => {
  it("tranform items by groups attribute", () => {
    const raw = { success: true, data: { products: [{ id: 1, name: 'product_name' }] } }
    const res = plainToInstance(ProductResponseInterface, raw, { groups: ["eshop.products", "eshop.products.product.name", "eshop.products.product.id"] })

    const exp: ProductResponseInterface = {
      success: true,
      data: {
        products: [
          {
            id: 1,
            name: "product_name"
          }
        ],
        groups: undefined,
        count: undefined,
      }
    }

    expect(res).toEqual(exp);
  });
});
```